# Python, Selenium how to get unique elements by xpath into list?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium with Python to get all siblings of xpath class.

My outcome is something like this:

```
proper_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="class_name"]')
```

As the outcome instead of unique values in that list, I am getting list of all elements.

So instead of

```
[WebElem1, WebElem2, WebElem3]
```

i am getting

```
[WebElem[::], WebElem[::], WebElem[::]]
```

There should be simple explanation. Can You help me?

Comment: you'll receive a list of object references...  you can then get attributes of "innerHTML" and "outerHTML" to get the html if that's what you're after.

Comment: Could you add some html of the elements you are trying to get?

Comment: if class name is for parent node use  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="class_name"]/child::*') and if it is for one of the siblings use  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="class_name"]/following-sibling::*')